# Strange behavior, Erlang ssl:connect work only in first call

Tags: ssl, https, erlang

I have small web server on my host. And I try to connect them with https.

I have next test function

```
request2(Host)->
    ssl:start(),
    {ok, Socket} = ssl:connect(Host, 8013, [{active, false},{certfile,"/home/user/sipo.pem"}], 10000),    
    ssl:close(Socket).
```

and in repl we have next:

```
(emacs@host-15)112> ssl:start().
ok
(emacs@host-15)113> test:request2("192.168.31.57").
ok
(emacs@host-15)114> test:request2("192.168.31.57").
** exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,closed}
     in function  test:request2/1 (/home/user/src/test.erl, line 78)

(emacs@host-15)117> ssl:stop().
ok
(emacs@host-15)118> ssl:start().
ok
(emacs@host-15)119> test:request2("192.168.31.57").
ok
(emacs@host-15)120> test:request2("192.168.31.57").
** exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,closed}
     in function  test:request2/1 (/home/user/src/test.erl, line 78)
(emacs@host-15)121>
```

Why the call request2 is work fine only once and afrer that I have error {error,closed}. Whot is happend?

Comment: What server are you connecting to? Is it possible that it accepts one connection and then exits?

Comment: I tested it in two nodes now. As result it depend only of ssl restarting, but not depend of node count

Comment: Using Erlang/OTP 18.3 I tried the same code as your `test:request2/1` along with the same sequence of ssl start/stop calls from the shell against a Yaws SSL server endpoint, and I wasn't able to duplicate your results.